# How to handle dialog boxes/prompts using selenium for python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape the website https://www.airliftexpress.com/.

As you can see, this is a grocery delivery app/website. Whenever you open their webpage, they first ask you your location/address in a dialog box that pops up. Once that dialog box is taken care of, only then the actual link opens up.

I try to use selenium to open the required webpage but don't know how to deal with the box that comes up. I have the country name, city name and coordinates of the location I will choose as address, only want to know how to communicate this information to the webpage using my script.

I hope I am clear about my query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage you are dealing with runs scripts while loading. you need to let the thread sleep some seconds and wait for loading to complete, then your code can find elements by class name or tag name.

also if you faced with the proglem of browser modal dialogs, you can use "alert" module.
wants examples,take a look here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-alert-prompts-in-selenium-python/